# QGIS color picker works only inside application

Tags: qgis

Tried to use QGIS Color picker for picking color for layer outside the QGIS window.
When Color picker is out of QGIS desktop application window, it changes to a simple cursor. Windows 8 x64, Windows 7 x86, x 64). However, everything works fine on my notebook (Windows 7 x64).
QGIS version - 2.18.

Comment: Is it only the preview which does not change or also when you click to pick the color?

Comment: I thought that color-picker in general works only inside the QGIS window - in older versions as well as in 3.8.2. Do you have any information that it shoud work outside QGIS? When I move the cursor with color-picker from QGIS to another window (like web-browser) and press the mouse-button, the cursor is activated in the browser: if I hit e.g. on a button, a new website opens.

Comment: Try pressing "space" when it's over an external window

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. The paint brush is activated and shown in the layer property window when I click on "pick colour". However the paint brush disappeared as soon as I hover the cursor outside of this window, and is replaced by an arrow. Clicking on a desired colour with the arrow does not work (I have tried). I am using both an iMac (QGIS3.10) and a MacBook Air (QGIS3.22) and both machine do not work.